# Returning data via the error handler in an http.get in angular2

Tags: http, angular, angular2-observables

Trying to figure out something which probably has an obvious answer to someone not new to observables and angular2.

I am calling an http.get to fetch data from the server. However if there is some kind of error I want to return a predefined set of data.
I realize that in my subscribe error function I can just load the pre-defined data there, but I want the service to take care of it.

So if I have a service doing this...

```
  getCategories(): Observable<string[]>  {

  return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/categories/')
                .map(this.extractData)
                .catch(this.handleError);


}


private handleError (error: Response | any) {
  let errMsg: string = "some error message"
  //want to return a constant here return CATEGORIES;
  return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

Instead of calling

```
return Observable.throw(errMsg);
```

How can I return data from the .catch function so that the subscriber wont know the difference - ie that its getting predefined data rather than data from the server.

My service call would look like this

```
this.myService.getCategories().subscribe(
                   cats => { this.categories = cats; },
                   error => {
                       console.log('Could not fetch categories', error)
                       //could do this but want it in service
                      //this.categories = CATEGORIES
                     },
                    () => console.log('Unknown error in get categories'));
```

Is there a different way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/categories/')
           .map(this.extractData)
           .catch(() => Observable.of(CATEGORIES));
```

See [the documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-catch)

Comment: Thanks. I had tried doing that before but my typescript wont compile...tells me Property 'of' does not exist on typeof Observable???

Comment: Ok my bad. Didnt realize I also had to import 'of
'import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
Thanks for the help